# User Profile picture not displaying on the template but saved to media File

Tags: django

I want the user profile picture to be displayed on the user dashboard after login, the image saves into the media file, i can display every other details pertaining to the user, but the image is not displaying, the picture is been uploaded when the user wants to update profile details, and not at the point of signup, please any help is appreciated ..Thanks a lot .

template

```
 <img class="profile-user-img img-responsive img-circle"
                                 src="{{ request.user.get_profile.picture.url }}" alt="User profile picture">

                            <h3 class="profile-username text-center">{{ user.full_name }}
                            {% if user.is_verified %}<i class="fa fa-check btn-primary img-circle"></i>{% endif %}

                            </h3>
```

views.py

```
def image_update(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        image = request.FILES['image']
        # profiles = get_object_or_404(Profile,user=request.user)
        try:
            profile = get_object_or_404(Profile,user=request.user)
        except Profile.MultipleObjectsReturned:
            profile = Profile.objects.filter(user=request.user)[0]
        profile.picture = image
        profile.save()

        return redirect('app:preferences')
    else:
        raise Http404
```

models.py

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, related_name='profile', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    picture = models.ImageField(blank=True, default='user.png', upload_to='images/')
```

Comment: Is the `DEBUG` setting set on `DEBUG = False` in your settings?

Comment: Do you have a `get_profile` method on the User class? Your related_name is `profile`, so you should probably use `request.user.profile.picture.url`. But also, do you actually have anything set up to serve images from MEDIA_URL?

Comment: yes i have a get_profile method

Comment: ```
  def get_profile(self, user_id):
        profile = Profile.objects.get(user_id=self)
```

Comment: What? Where is that method defined? Why does it take a user_id?

Comment: its defined in the models.py file and the method is place under CustomUser class, and it takes the user_id so as to be a signed user

Comment: But you will get a TypeError when you call it, because it expects a user_id parameter which you are not supplying. But you *never use* that parameter anyway, so you should remove it.  But once again *the entire method is pointless* because it does exactly the same job as the built-in accessor: `request.user.profile`.

Comment: ok @ Daniel....tho i have tried this {{ request.user.profile.picture.url }} but still not displaying..when i inspect from the chrome browser i see img src(unkn)